# Laravel 5.6 Inject variable with Service Provider in a group of routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a part of site that starts with specific prefix  `/manage`. 
Can I somehow like with `AppServiceProvider` view-composers inject a variable in all routes from that prefix?

I tried to do it by passing this variable to layout of all that routes. But then I met a problem. I use this variable in blade view of specific page, and it returns me `variable not defined`.
Then, I inspect laravel debugger and saw the order of loading of blade files. And it was : 
`1. Current page view
 2. Layout view
 3. Sidebars and other stuff`
 So, the fact that current page is loaded before layout, cause error of `undefined variable`.

So, how can I solve that ? Thanks.

Code from my Service provider :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\CT;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(['website.implicare.ct.show', 'website.implicare.ct.petition.index', 'layouts.ct'], function($view) {
            $ct = request()->ct;

            $permissions = [];
            foreach($ct->userPermissions(auth()->id()) as $userPermission) {
                if($userPermission->pivot->ct_id == $ct->id) {
                    array_push($permissions, $userPermission->name);
                }   
            }

            $view->with('permissions', $permissions);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code that didn't work?

Comment: @AdreAstrian sure, check my edit please.
That function is getting permissions for selected "CT", and pull that array to specific views. But I need it in like ~50 my views, so I trying to find a better solution than including this array of views, where to include that variable.
I'm trying to check if route is `'/manage*`, to include that variable.

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to do something depending on the `$permissions` variable in your view files. And you have like 50+ views. And you don't want to include 50+ view names in the array. Right? Don't you have a common layout for all those views? If not, can't you just use `*` meaning for all views? And limit your code execution for the current route match logic?

About the `variable not defined` is this occurring if you do the way, you showed in your code? Because I don't get this error. If this is your issue then please let us know when and how you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

create ComposerServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $theme = 'mytheme';

    public function boot()
    {

        view()->composer($this->theme.'.includes.navbar', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MenuComposer');
       view()->composer($this->theme.'.includes.header', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MenuComposer');

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```